# Selected element within list in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I want to apply different style for selected element from a long list.
I'm passing to React component element as props: **currentId** and **selectedId**.
Inside render function, I compare both ids and apply proper styles.

When clicking any element from the list, I fire an action with the new selected Id and all elements in the list will re-render(because **selectedId** prop does change).

If the list has 1000 element and I click one of them, It would be nice to only update 2 elements (new selected and deselected ones) not all of them.

Is these a better way to handle this scenario in React?

**Update: Add code example**

List component:

```
const MyList = (props) => {
    const items = props.items;
    const selectedId = props.selectedId;
    return (
        <div>
            {items.map((item) => (
                <MyItem
                    currentId={item.id}
                    selectedId={selectedId}
                    key={item.id}
                    content={props.content}
                />
            ))}
        </div>
    );
};
```

Item component:

```
const MyItem = (props) => {
  const isSelected = props.currentId === props.selectedId;
  return (
    <div className={isSelected ? 'selected-item' : ''}>
      <h1>{props.currentId}</h1>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: please share component code

Comment: Without seeing any code I would guess you are looking for help with an onClick function?  
onClick={this.doSomething}... doSomething(event) { event.target.id etc etc}

Comment: What is *currentId* for?

Comment: passing a props isSelected maybe better then react will rerender the components that have the props change only

Answer (score 0):

You can implement `shouldComponentUpdate` logic to prevent components from rerendering. Generally this is a bad idea (more on that later) but it does seem to apply to your use case. In general it is better to simply use `PureComponent` to prevent unneeded rerenders. This implements `shouldComponentUpdate` logic that compares `state` and `props` and if neither has changed, no update occurs.

Without seeing your code this is my best guess as to what `shouldComponentUpdate` might look like in your context:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
  if(this.state.isSelected && this.state.id !== nextProps.selectedId) {
    return true;
  } else if (!this.state.isSelected && this.state.id === nextProps.selectedId) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Note that this means that a rerender **will not happen** unless `shouldComponentUpdate` returns true or you call `this.forceUpdate()` on that component. Your component won't even render if `this.setState()` is called, unless you add in more specific logic so that `shouldComponentUpdate` returns true on state changes. This can lead to difficult to debug problems, where your UI fails to reflect changes in application state but no obvious error occurs. This behavior doesn't apply to child components, so if these components have children they will still rerender as expected. If you decide to implement `shouldComponentUpdate`, you can add logic to compare state as well by declaring the `nextState` parameter:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
  if(this.state.isSelected && this.state.id !== nextProps.selectedId) {
    return true;
  } else if (!this.state.isSelected && this.state.id === nextProps.selectedId) {
    return true;
  } else if (/*compare this.state to nextState */) { .... }
  return false;
}
```

Implementing your own `shouldComponentUpdate` is tricky, and may require you to restructure your code for best results (for example, passing an `isSelected` variable to your components instead of allowing those components to decide whether or not they are selected might allow you to easily implement `PureComponent`). Best of luck!